# Handling app updates (AlarmManager)

Tags: android

I am developing an app that connects to and modifies data in a database by executing php files.

If I need to make changes to the database or php files, this may cause old versions of the app to behave unexpectedly and crash. For this reason, I want to *force users* to *update* the app when such changes are made.

Right now, I have a method that connects to the database and compares the apps version to the databases version. This works fine but I call it every time I access the database (very often) which significantly slows down the usage of the app. Is there a better way to do this? I have read that I could use an `AlarmManager` or `BroadcastReceiver` to check for updates every X amount of hours. But what if the user closes and doesn't use the app for a few days. Will these timers get called as soon as the user starts the app and thus be able to force an update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android AlarmManager is an API that let you communicate and program alarm with the Android Alarm Service. Think of it as similar to a Linux Cron job. As soon as the alarm is programmed, then it'll be triggered even if your app isn't running, because the alarm is triggered by the alarm service and not by your app. For instance, the only thing you need to do is to program your alarm. It's important to note that when you restart your device then your alarms are cleared, so you need to reprogram then in every reboot. You can do this by capturing the [BOOT_COMPLETED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) broadcast, so you can reprogram your alarm every time the device boots up. Check out the definition of the [Android AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). A common pattern to do what you want is to program an alarm that sends a broadcast or starts a service, then in that service you can query your server. You need to consider that when the device is sleeping then the alarms couldn't be sent, so you need to work with [wakelocks](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html). This class will help you with that, [check it out](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html).

Comment: Thanks. I will consider using this method.